# How to avoid runtime error 70 when exporting cell values from various worksheets to text files

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: VBA Runtime Error 70

When I call the Sub Procedure "writeTxt" from another Sub Procedure I receive an error message "Runtime Error 70" with code line "Open strDatei1 For Output As #1"

When I step through the code with "F8" it works just fine, no error message and all variables have the correct value. The content of all worksheets is printed to the correct *.txt files.

Does anyone have an idea of how to avoid the error message?

```
Sub writeTxt()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim nameSheet As String
Dim strDatei1 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For x = 29 To 40
        nameSheet = Sheets("CodeData").Cells(x, 1).Value
        strDatei1 = Sheets("CodeData").Cells(x, 2).Value

        Sheets(nameSheet).Select
        Set Rng = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

            Open strDatei1 For Output As #1               
                For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To Rng.columns.Count
                cellValue = Rng.Cells(i, j).Value
                If j = Rng.columns.Count Then
                    Print #1, cellValue
                Else
                    Print #1, cellValue,
                End If
                    Next j
                Next i
            Close #1
    Next x

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you haven't assigned a value to `nameSheet` and `strDatei1`, I couldn't find anything wrong with your code. For some reason, I had to put the file path as a string literal in the `Open` statement, otherwise I was getting an error 75 for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. The values of `nameSheet` and `strDatei1` are stored in another sheet of the same workbook. When I run the code in debug mode the values of these two variables are shown correctly. It seems to me that it may be a time problem; perhaps the former procedure did not release the files yet?

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, before you can open a file you must have closed it using its handle so, if that didn't happen, then it's very likely that could be the problem.

Comment: I have checked that with a "fileOpen" check and all files are status "closed". I believe it is a time error. Another process has not released these files and I cannot find any answers on how to check and wait until the process has released the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't always use `As #1` to access a file. Use [FreeFile](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080557178.aspx) to get the next available file number instead:

```
Dim fileNumber As Integer

fileNumber = FreeFile
Open strDatei1 For Output As #fileNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too and it did not change the VBA behavior. I separated the sub "writeTxt" from the other sub procedures and run this sub alone. Then there is no problem. The problem arises only if this sub WwriteTxt" is called by another sub procedure.